# how to add registration and allow registered user to post on my blog?

Tags: web, blogs, blogger

how to add registration and allow registered user to post on my blog?

i have a blog and i want to add a registration feature to my blog and allow registered user to post article on my blog.

please someone tell me how to achieve this task.

i created new blog from Google blogger it's "http://ollmobileapps.blogspot.com/"

and i don't have any code for this that's why i'm asking b.coz i have seen some blogs in which i found registration and submit article?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess your code?

Comment: i created new blog from Google blogger it's "http://ollmobileapps.blogspot.com/"

and i don't have any code for this that's why i'm asking b.coz i have seen some blogs in which i found registration and submit article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats Not Possible With Blogger.Try Wordpress